# City names out of order during reverse geocoding using maps api in a for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I am reverse geo-coding a bunch of coordinates using a for loop and storing the result of each iteration in an array on node.js. However, when I send the array to my angular front-end or log it in the console, the order of the cities is randomized. I am using the @google/maps wrapper for node.js. Here is my code:

```
var gm = require('@google/maps').createClient({
    key: '**********************************'
});
var x, z;
var places = [];
gm.directions({
origin: 'NYC',
destination: 'Washington DC',
}, function(err, response) {
    if (!err) {
        for(i=0; i<response.json.routes[0].legs[0].steps.length; i=i+3) {
            x = response.json.routes[0].legs[0].steps[i].end_location; //getting the coordinates of the end location for each step
            gm.reverseGeocode({latlng: [x.lat, x.lng],}, function(err, response){
                if (!err) {
                    z = response.json.results[4].address_components[1].long_name + ', ' + response.json.results[4].address_components[2].short_name;
                    places.push(z);

                }
            });

        }
    }
});
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(places);
}, 5000)
```

I would really appreciate it if you could tell me what I am doing incorrectly here. Thanks.

UPDATE:

[result of console.log(response.json.results[4])](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FE8Ye.png)
[result of console.log(g)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXC8i.png)

Comment: Its an async method call, there is no guarantee that it will be handled synchron.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, when you are working with async code, you shouldn't rely on `setTimeout` to getting a value. Sometimes the `timeout` would not be enough and you will get wrong data.

You can use `callbacks`, `async/await` and `Promises` solutions to handle async operations and guarantee the correctness of data.

Getting your example:

```
let gm = require("@google/maps").createClient({
  key: "**********************************",
  Promise: Promise
});

let x, z;
let places = [];

const directionsPromise = gm
  .directions({
    origin: "NYC",
    destination: "Washington DC"
  })
  .asPromise()
  .then(response => {
    let geocodePromises = [];

    for (i = 0; i < response.json.routes[0].legs[0].steps.length; i = i + 3) {
      x = response.json.routes[0].legs[0].steps[i].end_location;

      gecodePromises.push(
        gm.reverseGeocode({ latlng: [x.lat, x.lng] }).asPromise()
      );
    }

    return Promise.all(geocodePromises);
  })
  .then(geocodes => {
    return geocodes.map(g => {
      return (
        g.json.results[4].address_components[1].long_name +
        ", " +
        g.json.results[4].address_components[2].short_name
      );
    });
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));


directionsPromise.then(geocodes => {
    // if you need
    places = geocodes;

    console.log(geocodes);
})
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: I have tried using promises in this exact way, and like last time, I get this error while running this code as well: 

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'address_components' of undefined
    at geocodes.map.g (C:\Users\sarim\Desktop\DS_Project1\myWaypoints2\backend\app.js:52:27)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at gm.directions.asPromise.then.then.geocodes (C:\Users\sarim\Desktop\DS_Project1\myWaypoints2\backend\app.js:50:21)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
undefined

Comment: Can you show what in `console.log(g)` in `map` function? I don't know the exact signature of `reverseGeocode` response.

Comment: Updated the post with screenshots @Ivan Burnaev

Answer (score 0):

log after for loop, and check the iteration (i=i+3)